# OnClick of calendar icon Calendar is not opening Jquery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, calendar, bootstrap-modal

I have used a **Jquery Datepicker** in my project on `input=text` element. Whenever I click on an input element my calendar is opened. But whenever I click on the `icon` of the datepicker, my calendar is not getting opened. I am imaging why it is happening like this.

Below is my html

```
<span class="datepicker"><input type="text" id="feRouteDate" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

Also see my jquery for the same

```
$(function () {
    $("#feRouteDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        maxDate: 0
    });
});
```

So, how should I get the calendar opened on click of its icon. Below is how it looks like when the page is loaded

[image: Calendar Icon]

Comment: may be try binding the event globally. $(document).on("click", ".fa-calendar", function() { $(".datepicker").show() });

Answer (score 1):

Default behavior of a calendar that it only opens when associated input box is `clicked`. However you can `open` it on click of other `elements` as well. Use:

```
$("#some-element").click(function(){
  $('#my-date-picker').datepicker( "show" );
})
```

So modify your code:

**HTML:**

```
<span class="datepicker"><input type="text" id="feRouteDate" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" id="icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){    

  $('#feRouteDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        altField: '#thealtdate',
        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });

    $("#icon").click(function(){
    $('#feRouteDate').datepicker( "show" );
    })
});
```

Comment: its not the accurate answer, if I had 100 calendar input, so should I add 100 on click event ?

Comment: I think some single `generic` method may do that for you.

Comment: yes, may be that is available in `datepicker` but I am not sure.. any guesses or trick from your side ?

Comment: I only find this `work around`. may be you can use some class on all your `icons` then `show` the `closest` datepicker on click or `pass` datepicker `id` to `click` event. something like that

Answer (score 1):

The `click` event on the `calendar` should show the calendar by using `datepicker.("show")`

Use `siblings("input")` will allow to detect the nearest `input` of the calendar icon that should open its datepicker.

```js
//set all your datepickers inputs
$("#feRouteDate,#feRouteDate2").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        maxDate: 0
    });
    
   
//You can show datepicker on click on the calendar icon
$(".fa-calendar").on("click", function(){
        $(this).siblings("input").datepicker("show");    
    });
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>datepicker demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span class="datepicker"><input type="text" id="feRouteDate" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> <br>

<span class="datepicker"><input type="text" id="feRouteDate2" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

</body>
```

Comment: i cant set all input as `datepickers`.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to (in addition to adding the "show" functionality to the button) disable the default behavior that the calendar shows when you click the textbox, so that the calendar only shows when you click the button?

Answer (score -1):

You can just add a click event to that `fa-calendar` element.

```
$('.fa-calendar').click(function () {
    $('#feRouteDate').datepicker();
});
```